# analyzed vs not_analyzed index search performance in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch with one shard one replica for each indices. Each day I create 3-5 indices and one of indices store approximately 1 million docs. Each docs has 6-10 columns. My question is that is there a huge difference between search performance of analyzed and not_analyzed indices in my db?

Answer (score 1):

Analysed fields would have a minor performance impact, but only when you index a document and not when you search. This is because the fields set to `analyzed` would have to run through the configured analyser chain (tokenisers, filters) when indexed.

Answer (score 1):

If field is not analyzed, it is like filter. i.e. yes or no. I mean if field is not analyzed, we can use those fields for filters [exact value match].

Normally we analyse the fields which contains unstructured data. If field is analysed, we can do full text search for the content which is available in fields value, and obviously full text search is slower than filters.

In general, before doing the full text search [analysed fileds], we need to apply the filters [use, non analyzed fields], so number of documents on which we need to apply the full test search query will be less.

Answer (score 0):

The question is - how you search? Is it matching queries or just filtering?